# MS MVC 3 custom html helper that recieve as parameter the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I've written a custom html helper in MVC 3 that receive as a parameter the model my view is based on. What I'm wondering is: can a custom helper access the model without receiving it as a parameter? Is there any way to avoid calling it like this: @html.MyCustomHelper(Model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504995.aspx) property of HtmlHelper to access the model

```
helper.ViewData.Model
```